# Having problems with .htaccess and Wamp

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla, wamp

I run a site using Joomla. Backed up to localhost running WAMP, and I have problems with .htaccess. Site is located in /www/sitename/

First, I had to comment out `IndexIgnore *` to get the site to load at all.
Now, it loads, but if I enable url rewriting, any local link I click on displays a page with my WAMP configuration.
My .htaccess is

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

The url is localhost/sitename

Comment: Did you create a Virtual Host for this site? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618 and http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,127757

Comment: Thank you! I had not created a virtual host and was able to do so automatically in the new version of WAMP. I was still getting the error until I saw the note about NOT using localhost in the url. That solved the problem.